# How to add or change value for a declared string using string(int, char) function?

Tags: c++, string

I know there is a way to give a value of a specific character being repeated n times to a string while declaring it, like this:

```
string example(int, char);
```

But what if I didn't give it a value initially, is it possible to use the repeated character function later?

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
string example;
example(int, char);
```

I got this error "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type"

Comment: It looks lik you are trying to call the constructor of an already initialized instance. You can just assign a new value `string example = "..."; /* more code */example = std::string(0, 'A');` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly that, but here's the next best thing.
If you need to increase/decrease size, you can use `std::string::resize()`, which has a second parameter to fill the new `char`s. So try this:

```
std::string foo;
foo.resize(10, 'A');
std::cout << foo << '\n';
```

And the output will be: `AAAAAAAAAA`

However, note that if you try this:

```
std::string a = "a";
a.resize(2, 'A');
```

`a` will become `"aA"`, because it does not overwrite the previous characters, only the new empty ones. To overwrite the previous ones, you can use `std::fill`:

```
std::string a = "aaa";
std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 'A');
```

And it'll become `"AAA"`.

[EDIT] As @churill said, reusing the constructor `a = std::string(10, 'A')` will also set the value of the string to `"AAAAAAAAAA"`, so you can use this as a simpler approach if you don't mind losing the previous value.